# How do I customise beamer_presentation RMarkdown layouts?

Tags: r, r-markdown

I'm only just starting to play around with RMarkdown, but I know that I will probably need to produce a PDF similar to a PowerPoint presentation as my final product, so I am using the `beamer_presentation` template to fiddle with.

The thing I'm currently running up against is I have no idea how to customise it with anything more intelligent than the default templates (e.g. AnnArbor, Frankfurt, etc).

For example, if I wanted to change the colour of headers, how do I do so?

With the `html_document` option you just add a CSS file with something like `color: green` under the `h1` section, but it looks like Beamer doesn't support the nice friendly options...

Answer (score 1):

As You noticed, the `css` argument cannot be used wit `output: beamer_presentation`

(Have a look at the [markdown reference](https://www.rstudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/rmarkdown-reference.pdf) for more on YAML options)

Instead, You can provide a custom Latex-preamble were You modify properties of the presentation - just as in a Latex document with `\documentclass{beamer}`:

```
---
title: "Awesome Title"
author: "Awesome Author"
date: "9/29/2017"
output: 
  beamer_presentation:
    includes:
      in_header: preamble.tex
---
```

For example set

`\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{fg=green}`

in preamble.tex to modify the header color.